# Use a different protocol than http or https for a submit button url redirection in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I am using a mobile app framework that has its own protocol for deep linking. I tried to use this protocol in the url redirection and the system denies it - it requires http or https only protocols. Can this be over-ridden?

Answer (score 1):

I work for support for Cognito Forms.  We only support http or https.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately this can not be overridden unless you take root ownership and modify the system files.